# Multiple key presses with dispatcher

Tags: java, swing, awt, keyevent

How should i modify my dispatcher class in order to catch multiple key presses?
For now i just want to print them...

```
class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
   System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());

} 

return false;
}
}
```

Comment: if user type N+J i want to print NJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with:

```
class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
ArrayList<String>typedKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) 
    typedKeys.add(""+e.getKeyChar());

if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
    String str = typedKeys+"";
    System.out.println(str.substring(1,str.length()-1).replaceAll(", ",""));
    typedKeys.clear();
 } 

return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Note that the sequence "press N", "press J", "release J", "press K", "release K", "release N" will fail with this approach. You should not clear the list on `KEY_RELEASED`, but only remove that key from the list, as @trashgod indicated in his answer. And there are more efficient ways to print an `ArrayList` then the one you are using.

Answer (score 3):

> If the user types `N+J`, I want to print `NJ`.

An attempt to press `N` and `J` simultaneously will result in one `KeyEvent` arriving after another. One approach is to create an `enum Key` similar to this [one](http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/Key.java?revision=27&view=markup). Using `EnumSet`, create a `Set current`. As `KEY_PRESSED` events arrive, update `current` to include the currently pressed keys plus the new one; as `KEY_RELEASED` events arrive, update `current` to exclude the new one. The method `current.equals()` will allow comparison to predefined key states used in your game.  Note that `EnumSet` instances are immutable but efficiently small for a reasonable number of keys.